# Teradata Select where date = previous workday/weekday

Tags: sql, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

Using Teradata 15.1x

I'm trying to select data for the previous weekday. I can get the previous day using

```
cast(cast(cast(a.date_dim_ck as varchar(13)) as date format 'yyyymmdd') as date format 'mm-dd-yyyy') = current_date - 1
```

but when I try to do a case when to look back 3 days on Monday instead of 1 (to get Friday's data, see below), I get "[3707] Syntax error, expected something like an 'END' keyword between ')' and '='."

```
where case 
when td_day_of_week(current_date)<>2 
then
cast(cast(cast(a.date_dim_ck as varchar(13)) as date format 'yyyymmdd') as date format 'mm-dd-yyyy') = current_date - 1
else
cast(cast(cast(a.date_dim_ck as varchar(13)) as date format 'yyyymmdd') as date format 'mm-dd-yyyy') = current_date - 3
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you just be missing the END keyword and the condition you are checking for? It should look like WHERE CASE WHEN Condition1 THEN Result1 END = expectedResult

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only use a case statement to determine the value of a field based on another criteria.  See syntax below.

```
where cast(cast(cast(a.date_dim_ck as varchar(13)) as date format 'yyyymmdd') as date format 'mm-dd-yyyy') = case  
    when td_day_of_week(current_date)<>2 
    then
     current_date - 1
    else
     current_date - 3
    end
```

Comment: Case when problem = solved then
you = wizard!
End

Thanks, Daniel!